# Android media player stops when open gallery

Tags: android, gallery, android-music-player

I developed a simple music player using MediaPlayer class. I played a song using it, minimize my music player, then I open native gallery, and my application get weird.

It becomes like stuck for a few seconds, and then it started to play new song.

I also did like that using android native player and the player paused when gallery opened.

Do you guys know what might cause my application stucked like that?

I really appreciate any help from you guys,

Regards,

Chrisma Andhika

Comment: did you tried with SoundPool ?

Answer (score 0):

see in your app, if you minimize your app it goes to onpause() state again come return to app it will call onresume() state. so it takes some time. there is nothing weird in this thing.

Comment: no, not like that. when I minimized it, I then opened gallery, then I stayed in gallery for about 6 seconds, than my music player suddenly stoped playing the music. I did not return to my music player, just stayed in gallery.

Comment: @ChrismaAndhika, can you post your code then only we can analyse your problem.

Comment: It just a simple media player using .setDataSource(), .start(), and .stop().